# What notable examples of metamorphic engines are there?

Tags: malware, obfuscation

I am doing a research project on metamorphic malware and would like to have access to a metamorphic engine I could demo. Are there any good open-source (or easily obtainable) metamorphic engines I could experiment with for this project?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "where can I find X?" are off-topic as the lists might be neverending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my point of view you can start with Metasploit and check the encoders that exist there, such as shikata-ga-nai, etc.... There are some articles interested https://www.cs.unm.edu/~crandall/ccsdacoda.pdf and http://lsd.ls.fi.upm.es/papers/2009/srds2009.pdf where you can find very useful references about the topic. Finally if you want to dig on how metamorphic techniques works I definitively you recommend starts with https://github.com/K2/ADMMutate that covers the most interested metaphoric techniques.